# Select field from table only when all rows paired to same ID have a date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve some info from the DB.

I have the following table

```
orderNo   item   shipping
 1050      1     0000-00-00    
 1050      2     0000-00-00
 1050      6     2016-09-18
 2000      2     0000-00-00
 2006      1     2016-09-05
 2006      2     0000-00-00
```

There are some orders paired with multiple items. When the item is 2, I want to automatically add a shipping date (that functionality works fine). But the script will need to be added ONLY when all the rest items has a date attached to them.

For example:
-> order number '1050': Item 6 has a date but Item 1 has no date, so we won't add shipping date to 2
-> order number '2000': There is only item 2 there, so we are good to go, shipping date will be added
-> order number '2006': Item 1 has a date, so again, we can add date to item 2 as well.

In other words, when the order has an item other than 2, and at least one of the other paired items has no shipping date then I want to ignore it

```
//adding the shipping date to item 2
$sql = "UPDATE orders 
        SET shipping = '".$shipping."'
        WHERE orderNo = '".$orderNo."' AND item = '2'";
Db::getInstance()->query($sql);

//add some kind of query to check whether shipping of rest items is not zero. If it is '0000-00-00' then do not proceed
SELECT orderNo FROM orders WHERE orderNo = '".$orderNo."' AND shipping in other items than 2 has a date
      //If query returns true then proceed and execute the following
      $new_payment = new itemPayment();
      //else do nothing
```

So in the above query, I am passing the order number (eg. '1050') and I somehow want to check if all the other items (other than 2) has a shipping date. If they all have then proceed, if not then do nothing.

I tried different queries but nothing worked. Can it be done only with mysql queries? or does it need some PHP code too?

would really appreciate if anything can help me with that or at least lead me to the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An understandable way to do this, is going for a query:

```
SELECT orderNo FROM orders WHERE orderNo = '".$orderNo."' AND item !=2 AND shipping>'0000:00:00'
```

Then run [php num rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to see how many rows match to your query. If the result is more than 0, that means you should not proceed

Comment: Hello, I think that might be a solution. But in the end it should be shipping equals 0000-00-00. Which means if it returns at least one row (other than item 2) with 0 date then don't proceed. I believe that should work. Thanks

Comment: You can alter the query at will. I only wanted to demonstrate the concept of using num rows to determine the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help you:

```
$sql = "Select orderNo from orders where item != '2' AND shipping > '2000-01-01'";
```

Alternative:

```
$sql = "Select orderNo from orders where item != '2' AND shipping > '0'";
```

Comment: Hello, that's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Just to make it more simple, I want to retrieve order numbers ONLY if their paired items (other than 2) has a date. Basically if you look in my table, eg order no 1050. The query I added in the bottom of my message shall not return anything. But if item 1 and 6 both have shipping date (and all are paired to order 1050 as you can see), then it is ok, proceed.  Hope it makes sense?

Comment: your query actually helped me, it doesn't work perfectly but with some modifications it should be fine (for example shipping should be equals to zero... so that if the query returns a row, that means an item other than 2 has a date equals to 0000-00-00 so it should not proceed). Thanks